# Thunderbird with Enigmail freezes

Tags: thunderbird, enigmail

It seems that the  [Enigmail extension](https://enigmail.net/) was updated today in my Ubuntu desktop machine. The version is now "Enigmail 2.1.8". However, after Thunderbird starts (and a few seconds pass) Thunderbird freezes.

I had to kill Thunderbird from command line and start it in "safe mode". Then I disabled the *Enigmail* extension in the *Add-ons Manager*. After restarting Thunderbird in normal mode, I no longer experience the hang.

Any ideas from users with same configuration?

System: Ubuntu 20.04.1. Thunderbird 68.10.0. (Fully updated system brings Thunderbird only to 68.10, while there are newer releases.)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Thunderbird 68.10.0 and Enigmail 2.1.8 on Ubuntu 18.04.5. The system is up-to-date.

The following works for me:

- kill all thunderbird instances
- start thunderbird in safe mode with add ons disabled

```
$ thunderbird --safe-mode
check "Disable all add-ons"
click "Continue in Safe Mode
```

- disable the enigmail plugin via the plugin administration

```
Tools->Add-Ons->Enigmail disable
```

- restart thunderbird in normal mode, it should not freeze anymore.
- activate the Enigmail plugin again via the plugin administration

```
    Tools->Add-Ons->Enigmail enable
```

It works for the current session, after a restart with enabled Enigmail add on there freezes again.

Comment: This was a permanent fix for me, not just a temporary one as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What was not apparent to me is that in the new versions of Thunderbird, not only is the Enigmail functionality incorporated into Thunderbird (there is a message to that effect when you first start the new version), but this functionality is incorporated WITHOUT the add-on. That is, the add-on can (and should) simply be removed, and the Enigmail functionality is preserved. It is unnecessary to start in safe mode and then re-enable the add-on. To solve this problem simply remove the add-on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this is not something that you need help with, so much as you've discovered a bug.

Check for an upgraded version of the host application (Thunderbird) and confirm the issue... after which go to [Bugzilla and check for an existing bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=thunderbird%20enigmail).

If you don't find one, then please log one so that they can make the fix.

Comment: I would like comments about users with the same configuration. Unfortunately Ubuntu does not update Thunderbird in it repositories as fast as it does for Firefox. Currently we are in version 68.10 in Ubuntu repositories, while there have been released more than 5 new releases of Thunderbird.

Comment: Ok yes I agree. My thought was that logging a bug report will often get a speedy response from the developers - faster than here, as I notice a few similar historical questions that have 0 answers. Pity Thunderbird has so many dependencies... so can't just as un-installed the repo-provided version, and then installed a bleeding-edge version to check.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I know for now is to disable internet access when starting Thunderbird with Enigmail enabled.

Then it starts fine and you can reenable internet access after that. It keeps working until restarted the next time.

If it is in the stuck state already, disable your internet connection briefly and Thunderbird will start responding.  Then you can re-enable your internet connection.