# How can I fix Thunderbird freezing - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Thunderbird is very slow / hangs / freezes.

I do not have this problem with other apps.  I have plenty of spare RAM.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks
DB

Comment: Is it related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273481/ ? Did you try to start it in "safe mode" and add-ons disabled?

Comment: When entering "./thunderbird" in the terminal I get "no such file or directrory". My path to thunderbird is /.thunderbird - when I type ".thunderbird" I also get "no such file or directory"

Comment: If you installed Thunderbird from Ubuntu repos, it should be at the path: `/usr/bin/thunderbird`

Comment: lol - just typing 'thunderbird' (in the correct directory) started it.  then did it in safe-mode with add-ons disabled but made no difference - still slow and hangs.  But your way - '/usr/bin/thunderbird' also worked.

Comment: You should describe the "slow", "hangs" and "freezes" words in more detail. You should give more information about your config: How many mail accounts (incoming servers) have you defined on Thunderbird? How many outgoing servers have you defined? Double check the **Server Settings** tabs for each account to check that server names (IPs?), ports, security settings, etc. are correct. Please, [edit] you original question and add any information that seems relevant to you.

Comment: Thanks - will do.